# Normal Derivative: Identity

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I don't really get this identity :
$$ \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial n} = \vec n . \nabla \Phi $$
So gradient is:
$$ \nabla \Phi = \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x}  \vec i +\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial y} \vec j +\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial z}  \vec k  $$
Normal vector is:

$$ \vec n = n_x \vec i + n_y \vec j+ n_z \vec k $$
RHS of identity:

$$\vec n . \nabla \Phi = n_x \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x} +  n_y \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial y} +  n_z \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial z} $$

So must be:

$$ \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial n} =  n_x \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x} +  n_y \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial y} +  n_z \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial z} $$

Now is my question, what is $n_x $ , so the components of the normal vector

Can this be true:
$$n_x = \frac{\partial x}{\partial n} $$

Answer (score 2):

The [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) $\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{B}}$ tells you how much of the vector $\mathbf{A}$ lies along the direction of the unitary vector $\mathbf{\hat{B}}$. If it is zero it means that they are perpendicular, if you get back $|\mathbf{A}|$ it means they were parallel.

Now, the gradient $\nabla \Phi$ is a vector and $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is usually an unitary vector. The product

$$
\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla \Phi
$$

Is then how much of the vector $\nabla\Phi$ is projected in the direction of $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$, or say in another words, it tells you what is rate of change of $\Phi$ along $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$, hence the name: [directional derivative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectionalDerivative.html), usually denoted as

$$
\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \mathbf{\hat{n}}} = \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla \Phi
$$

or as $\nabla_{\mathbf{\hat{u}}}\Phi$. But just to emphasize, it does not mean you are taking the derivative with respect a vector, only means that you are calculating the projection of the derivative along said vector

Comment: Hi, thanks for feedback.  But I still don't get how in the LHS the $\vec n $ pops in at $\frac {\partial \Phi} {\partial n} $

Comment: @dreckschweinhund Just a notation: the rate of change of $\Phi$ in the direction of $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$